# Get inside struct values

Tags: go, mgo

In this [example](https://github.com/bxcodec/go-clean-arch), I changed the `Sql driver` to `mgo`, I got some confusion. Here, How can I access the inside struct value? like nested struct.

I have two struct,

**Author**

```
type Author struct {
    ID        string `bson:"id"`
    Name      string `bson:"name"`
    Timestamp time.Time
}
```

**Article**

```
type Article struct {
    ID        bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Title     string        `bson:"title"`
    Content   string        `bson:"content"`
    Author    Author        `bson:"inline"`
    Timestamp time.Time
}
```

**Function**

```
func (m *mgoArticleRepository) FindAll() ([]*models.Article, error) {
    result := make([]*models.Article, 0)
    sessionCopy := m.Conn.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()
    collection := sessionCopy.DB(DBNAME).C(COLLECTION)
    err := collection.Find(nil).All(&result)
    return result, err
}
```

**Output**

Author object return empty (I have data in mongoDB)

```
[
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422cca",
        "Title":"Makan Ayam",
        "Content":"Sample values One",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422ccb",
        "Title":"Makan Ikan",
        "Content":"Sample values Two",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422ccc",
        "Title":"Makan Sayur",
        "Content":"Sample values Three",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422ccd",
        "Title":"Makan Daging",
        "Content":"Sample values Four",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422cce",
        "Title":"Makan Indomie",
        "Content":"Sample values Five",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "ID":"5b4f27c187a9e40828422ccf",
        "Title":"Makan Soto",
        "Content":"Sample values Six",
        "Author":{
            "ID":"",
            "Name":"",
            "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Timestamp":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
```

Here, How can I make the relationship for both structs? Thanks.

Comment: If you think of MongoDB as a drop in replacement for  RDBMS, you are going to run into problems. Taking your existing models and use them in MongoDB has a good chance of failing. In SQL, you try to figure out how to answer your questions based on relatively rigid modelling. With NoSQL in general and MongoDB in particular, you model your data so that your questions can be answered in the most efficient way. Subtle, but important difference.

Comment: Could we have a sample of your stored data, not just what returns from the call?

Answer (score 0):

change line:

```
Author Author `bson:"inline"
```

to

```
Author Author `bson:"Author"`
```

Comment: It will be return same output.

Comment: try `map[string]interface{}` instead of author type. lets make sure unmarshalling is the problem here